# How to get the sendto mail recipient in Xubuntu 14.04 to use Geary email client?

Tags: xubuntu, 14.04, geary

I have geary set as my default email client on Xubuntu 14.04 but when I try to use the send to mail recipient in Thunar I get an error [image] [image]
I am wanting to know how to make this possible without this error, and or why this error is occurring.

Comment: What is the theme of icon pack, color of panel and wallpaper you used? I love it :)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation yet to post a comment. I wanted to ask which theme are you using? I really like it. Thanks

Comment: @FarazAhmad looks like **Numix** Icons and Style

Comment: Link to the Bugreport for the problem https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=730048

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geary doesn't currently support this feature.  You can file a ticket requesting it [on GNOME's Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/).

Comment: That is weird cause I run it on Ubuntu and it seemed to work through the sendto with nautilus, unless they use different protocols for this action.

Comment: Yup, Nautilus sendto is a separate app that Geary explicitly supports.

Answer (score 0):

in Settings Manager  (xfce4-settings-manager), choose "Preferred Applications", then you can change what you want the system to use as defaults for Mail Reader, Browser, FileManager, and Terminal Emulator.

Comment: I have geary set there as the default but I still get that error.